# Passing a model object through ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a model object through ViewBag.  I tried the following codes but somehow in my View, it is only the path of the model which is displayed.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Tempo()
{
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);
    Employee emp = new Employee(3, "fara", "hass", date1, 56.6m, 0);
    ViewBag.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeID;
    ViewBag.Fname = emp.Fname;
    ViewBag.Employee = emp;
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tempo";
}

@model LayoutProject.Models.Employee

<h2>Tempo</h2>
<div>
    <h4>ViewBag</h4>
    <br />
    EmployeeID: @ViewBag.EmployeeId
    <br />
    Fname: @ViewBag.Fname
    <br />
    Employee : @ViewBag.Employee
</div>
```

The Fname and EmployeeId is correctly displayed but not the Employee itself.  Am I missing something here or it is simply not possible to pass a model through ViewBag?

Comment: You are passing the model using `ViewBag` but `@ViewBag.Employee` displays the `.ToString()` value of `Employee` There is no need to include `ViewBag.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeID;` and `ViewBag.Fname = emp.Fname;` - you can just use `ViewBag.Employee = emp;` and in the view - `EmployeeID: @((Employee)ViewBag.emp).EmployeeId` etc. But why do this instead of passing the model to the view - `return View(emp)`?

Comment: @tabby - What did you expect to see displayed for the Employee field?

Comment: @Stephen: so I can't use '@ViewBag.emp' to display the whole model with its properties?

Comment: @Dangerous: I thought ViewBag.emp would display the whole model. Is that possible?

Comment: @tabby - I expect you want to display the model as a string, but you need to dictate what format that string should be in.  You should either override the ToString() method of your employee object or create a field in a view model containing the information.

Comment: @tabby - The [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) ToString() will just display the object implementation which is a string that represents the object which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to create a **view model** to pass to the view:

```
public class TempoViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { private get; set; }
    public DateTime EmployeeStartDate { private get; set; }
    //any other properties here that make up EmployeeInformation

    public string EmployeeInformation
    { 
        get
        {
            //Format your employee information in the way you intend for the view
            return string.Format("Employee: {0}, {1}, {2}", this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.EmployeeStartDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Then have a **controller** create the view model:

```
public ViewResult Tempo()
{
    employee = //logic to retrieve employee information

    //map model to viewmodel
    var viewModel = new TempoViewModel()
    {
        EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeID,
        FirstName = employee.Fname,
        LastName = employee.Lname, //or set whatever properties are required to display EmployeeInformation
        EmployeeStartDate = employee.StartDate,
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And then display the view model in the **view**:

```
@model TempoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tempo";
}

<h2>Tempo</h2>
<div>
    <h4>Tempo Employee Information</h4>
    <br />
    EmployeeID: @Model.EmployeeId @* Do you really want to display the employee id? *@
    <br />
    Fname: @Model.FirstName
    <br />
    Employee: @Model.EmployeeInformation
</div>
```

---

**Update:**

With your current implementation, what you are trying to achieve when you call `@ViewBag.Employee` in the view, is to write the model out as a string representation.  With the current implementation, to convert the model to a string, the [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the model is called.  As you (probably) have not overridden the `ToString()` method, the inherited object implementation is called instead which writes out the complete namespace and class name (which is what I assume you mean when you say path).

To correct your current solution, you can add an implementation of `ToString()` to your Employee class.  For example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(int employeeId, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.EmployeeId = employeeId;
        this.FName = firstName;
        this.LName = lastName;
        //etc
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Implement your required string representation of the object here
        return string.Format("EmployeeId: {0}, FName: {1}, LName: {2}", EmployeeId, FName, LName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @tabby - How did you get on with this solution?

Comment: No, this is not what I want.  Here you are not using ViewBag.  What I want is to transfer a model from a controller to a view, using a ViewBag.  What I am getting when doing 'ViewBag.Employee = emp' in the controller and 'Employee :  @ViewBag.Employee' in the view, is the path of my model.  I want to display the model itself, not the path.  What  is wrong with the way I am doing it?

Comment: @tabby - Fair enough, I didn't directly answer your question.  I have provided an update to my answer.

Comment: That's what I wanted!  Thanks!