# how to get one item of the list in a foreach ViewBag mvc 5

Tags: c#, razor, viewbag, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-5.2

[image: The Result i want but Pending in a link]I want to get all the student have the ContractStatus == "Pending" in foreach and make a link to Edit the student

```
<div class="row">
     @{ foreach (var studentCohort in ViewBag.CohortSubscriptionId)
         {
         <div class="col-md-5">
              @{

                 var link = Html.ActionLink((string) studentCohort.ContractStatus, "Edit", "CohortSubscriptions", new { id = (object) studentCohort.ContractStatus }, new { @class ="form-control"});

                 var contractStatus = studentCohort.ContractStatus == "Pending" ? link : studentCohort;
               }

               @studentCohort.FullName  (@studentCohort.contractStatus)
          </div>
          }
      }
</div>

public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Cohorts cohorts = db.Cohorts.Find(id);
            if (cohorts == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var studentByCohort = db.Enrolled_Students.Where(x => x.CohortId == id).Select(x => new StudentCohortViewModel
            {
                CohortId = x.CohortId,
                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                ContractStatus = x.ContractStatus

            }).Distinct().ToList();
            ViewBag.CohortSubscriptionId = studentByCohort;

            return View(cohorts);
```

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''CodeboxxSchoolPortal.Models.StudentCohortViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'contractStatus''

Comment: We need more code to help you out.  The code for `StudentCohortViewModel` would greatly help.

Comment: done@PaulCarlton

Comment: Why not using `View Model` instead ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906975/passing-a-model-object-through-viewbag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice in variable names and reassignments are hurting you here. Consequently, you're getting your types mixed and the errors you experience.

Instead of the ternary conditional `(c ? a : b)`, I suggest using basic if/else which is easier to read and write.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach(StudentCohortViewModel studentCohort in ViewBag.CohortSubscriptionId)
    {
        if (studentCohort.ContractStatus == "Pending")
        {
            <text>
                @studentCohort.FullName (@Html.ActionLink(studentCohort.ContractStatus,
                                               "Edit",
                                               "CohortSubscriptions",
                                               new { id = student.ContractStatus },
                                               new { @class = "form-control" }))
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>
                @studentCohort.FullName (@studentCohort.ContractStatus)
            </text>
        }
    }
</div>
```

To help with identifying the correct type, instead of `var studentCohort` use the more explicit `StudentCohortViewModel studentCohort`.

Comment: I made some changes to your code, but it works thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

change

`(@studentCohort.contractStatus)`

to

`(@studentCohort.ContractStatus)`

in your Razor view.

Comment: I have already tried this, yes it gives me the ContractStatus but when the status is "Pending"' is not a link like i want

Comment: change `(@studentCohort.contractStatus)` to `(@contractStatus )`

Comment: "(XXXX.Models.StudentCohortViewModel)" i see that

Comment: Even for ones that are Pending? For all Students you see that?

Comment: `var contractStatus = studentCohort.ContractStatus == "Pending" ? link : studentCohort;` this is the problem statement in your code.

Comment: how you write it?